# Flutter: Device specific orientation

Tags: flutter, orientation

In flutter how would I disable landscape orientation in Mobile below 700 pixels width only? For any other device above this they are allowed to use landscape or portrait orientation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 600) {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    //Write your code here
    }else{
       //write your other code if needed
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, did not think of putting inside of the Widget build method. I have done this with the use of a external function to return a list<DeviceOrientation> to use inside of SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations.